# How do you animate the background of a TextView that has been defined in xml?

Tags: android, xml, animation, textview

For example I have the following as the background of a TextView:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval"
        android:id="@+id/pulsator">
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#77FF00" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            />
        <size
            android:height="8dp"
            android:width="8dp"/>
</shape>`

In the main activity I have:

```
txtMessageData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessageData);
```

The background is set in xml as:

```
<TextView
.
.
android:background="@drawable/pulsator />
```

Animating the TextView itself is easy but I actually only want to animate the background. Essentially I'm aiming to have rings pulsating concentrically away from the TextView too show that it is actively updating.

I would think maybe a property animation could be used but I have not found a way to do it.

I have the following animation set defined in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
/>

<scale
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="2.5"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="2.5"
/>
</set>
```

Can this animation data be applied to the background of my TextView?

Comment: Up to I know you can animate your textView but not it's background

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a LinearLayout and put into it your text view then animate this linearLayout... try it.